# input and outputs different address in the same wallet but address not exist!

Tags: payment, sending, verification

Dear Bitcoin Community members. I am using Bitcoin Core version v24.0.1.
I have recieved funds to this address: bc1qfewsp4zw738qd26a5wsgsq3j8hmjau5zz4d8je

I have sent funds using SendMany function with this txId:
ec5b35a5f0e237781f5d47d39e3fc3bf06f99edfe5670c2496b4e2748bfcc661

It seems my funds not sent from the address that I have received and sender address not belong to any of address I have seen in my wallet.

Despite that I have made many successful transactions, today I have noticed, one of my transaction received by one address, and sent by another! However there is no internal transactions.

When I search by blockchain explorer, I don`t see any connection about fund!

What could be the problem? I have asked ChatGtp, he has warned if my account is compromised!.

Kind Regards

Comment: According to its makers ["ChatGPT sometimes writes plausible-sounding but incorrect or nonsensical answers."](https://openai.com/blog/chatgpt/) - it is more an experiment in language processing that has very little access to truth. I would not rely on it at all. It is a charming liar, as happy to deceive as to inform.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. It is true most cases. But It is good to listen sometimes giving valuable information.

Answer (score 2):

The `sendmany` RPC takes a JSON object of key-value pairs, where the key is the bitcoin address you are sending to and the value is the amount to send to that address. The inputs are automatically chosen by the wallet. For more information, check `bitcoin-cli help sendmany`.

If you want to specify which UTXOs to use as inputs in a transaction, you can use the `send` RPC and pass a list of inputs in the `options` object. You will need to know the transaction ids and vouts of the UTXOs you want to spend, which you can get by running `bitcoin-cli listunspent`. See `bitcoin-cli help send` and `bitcoin-cli help listunspent` for more information and examples.

With regards to your transaction, I can see that you specified three outputs to spend to and your wallet automatically chose an input to fund the transaction.

Comment: Send function warning like "Experimental" makes me scared to try, but Thanks for the detailed info. I will make some trials.

Comment: You can always practice using these commands on signet or testnet and I strongly recommend doing so before using the commands with real money on mainnet.

Comment: Thanks Josie for your valuable comments and time.